# VBscript running shell command script works but does nothing

Tags: vba, vb.net, excel, vbscript

I am trying to write a code to open an excel file by clicking a .vbs file but although the code executes the file does not get opened. When I type the same command in the CMD the file opens up perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub RunMacro()
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("C:\Desktop\CompanyAlerts.xlsm")
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me (with a test file).  How is the above related to clicking a .vbs file? I ran it as a vba macro inside of Excel.

Comment: Yeah sorry I am teaching myself all things VB and I assumed that I could run the macro command as a VBScript. I will check how to get it to work as a vbs script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open notepad and put the following in and save as .vbs

```
Option Explicit
Sub Example() 
  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\CompanyAlerts.xlsm", 0, True) 
  xlApp.Application.Visible = True
    'xlApp.Quit 
   ' Set xlBook = Nothing 
 ' Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can then right-click and run, or call this vbs from command line.